# Why cublas copy algorithm is so fast in cuda?

Tags: algorithm, cuda, copy, cublas

I wrote kernel that copied input vector to output vector.
But the performance is not enough compared to cublascopy API.
The cublasScopy is almost 100 times faster than my kernel in case of 1M elements.
Anyone knows about algorithm of cublascopy?

```
__global__ void copy_kernel(const float *rv1, int inc1, float *rvo, int inco, int n)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    while (tid < n)
    {
        rvo[tid*inco] = rv1[tid*inc1];
        tid += (blockDim.x * gridDim.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can certainly write a copy kernel that is as fast as cublasScopy.  However it's not possible to be certain about what is wrong in your test case.  You might be compiling a debug code.  You might have values for `inc1` and `inco` that are different from 1.  And I imagine there are other possiblities.  You should probably provide a complete test case, including showing your measurements.  Presumably you have all that code, as you've made the comparison already, right?  Why not show your whole test case, including your kernel, your cublas code, your measurement code, i.e. a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Robert's help.

I found that measurement code had a bug.
I have to add cudaDeviceSynchronize() only for measuring performance.
And then above my kernel is a little bit slower than cublasScopy.
I think it is reasonable.

```
// cuBLAS Algorithm
timer.onTimer(4);
cublasScopy(handle, num_data, d_i_vals, inc1, d_o_vals, inco);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();     // this dummy line is needed only for measurement purpose
timer.offTimer(4);

timer.onTimer(5);
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(o_vals, d_o_vals, sizeof(float) * o_buf_size, 
                            cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
timer.offTimer(5);
```